# Android ndk static load (perform task after launching app)

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

Before I can use C++ library in my project with NDK I should load it use:

```
static {
  try { 
     System.loadLibrary("MyLibrary.so");
  }
}
```

MyLibrary.so contains method `jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved)` which start perform after load. So maybe there's a way that load library after start application without performing load method (I want that my C++ library performs something after user launches application without straight execution). Also, I can't extending of Application.

Comment: What does _"perform something without straight execution"_ mean?

Comment: It's mean when user starts application, library detects it (or maybe detect if library loaded) and performs some task for example checksum

Comment: I think dlopen is what you are looking for.

Comment: @CherkesgillerTural can I have some example of implementation pls?